# Ignore image via opengraph sharing?

Tags: wordpress, sharing, facebook-opengraph

So I am running into an issue that I cannot find an answer to. I am trying to put a tag on an image so that open graph will IGNORE that image. I have a share post button on my blog and facebook / pinterest always pulls the avatar image instead of the featured image. So I would like to put a tag on my avatar image to be ignored when sharing. I could put open graph information specifically on each image but then every post I have something to do, whereas if I could ignore the profile image it would work perfect.

Comment: Would be a fine idea.